# Div popup over jQuery border layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a Border Layout. When i click any link i am trying to open a Div popup.

Problem is the div popup is not appearing in the screen.

Below is the style of div popup.

```
.divclose {
    color:#993300;
    text-decoration:none;
    float:right;
}

.divbody {
    width:70%;
    padding:5px;
    border:2px solid #EFEFEF;
    background-color:#FEFEFE;
}
```

Do i need to modify the css to make the div popup appear on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

When using a div layer as popup you should set a z-index. Try this code

```
* {
    z-index: 1;
}

.divclose {
    color: #993300;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
    z-index: 2;
}

.divbody {
    width: 70%;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #EFEFEF;
    background-color: #FEFEFE;
    z-index: 2;
}
```